# Getting delayed/no response on mobile

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-authentication, expo

I am using firebase for react-native with expo. When i use the createUser, the resolve function doesn't work correctly, i need to re-render the component to see the response.`

```
const login = useCallback(async () => {

    try {

      const response = await firebase
        .auth()
        .signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password);

      console.log("response", response);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log("erreur code", error.code);
      setError(error.code);
      setLoading(false);
    }
  }, [name, email, password]);
```